# GoLang: Reading and casting bytes into struct fields

Tags: reflection, file-io, go

I am reading from an `io.Reader` into a Struct, field by field.

```
// structFields returns a sequence of reflect.Value
for field := range structFields {
    switch field.Kind() {
    case reflect.String:
        // Omitted
    case reflect.Uint8:
        value := make([]byte, 2)
        reader.Read(value)

        var num uint8
        err := binary.Read(bytes.NewBuffer(value[:]), binary.LittleEndian, &num)
        if err != nil { return err }
        field.SetUint(int64(num))
    // Case statements for each of the other uint and int types omitted
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the block for reflect.Uint8 needs to be repeated for each of the Uint and Int data types since I need to create the `var num` correctly in each case.

Is there a way I can simplify this switch statement?

Comment: Although this does not solve this exact problem, you could replace all this logic with a simple call to [binary.Read()](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary#Read) which reads in all the fields of a struct in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `var num uint8` and `field.SetUint(int64(num))` just pass a pointer to the struct field to `binary.Read`:

```
ptr := field.Addr().Interface()
err := binary.Read(bytes.NewBuffer(value[:]), binary.LittleEndian, ptr)
```

And make the case statement say:

```
case reflect.Uint8, reflect.Int, reflect.Uint, ...:
```

Then you need to deal with differently-sized numbers. Fortunately you can just pass your reader directly to `binary.Read` and it'll take care of it:

```
err := binary.Read(reader, binary.LittleEndian, ptr)
```

Finally, as FUZxxl says, you can just pass a pointer to the entire struct to `binary.Read` and it'll do all this for you.

Comment: @FUZxxl's solution wouldn't work unless all fields are sized ints, floats or complexes, it wouldn't work with any kind of a slice or a string.

Comment: Speaking of string fields, any recommendations on how to read those? I am trying to use a tag on the struct field, but I can not get to tags from a reflect.Value